# Sequential composition for arbitrary number of calls in Vertx with Futures

Tags: future, vert.x

We use Futures in vertx in examples like:

```
Future<JsonObject> fetchVehicle = getUserBookedVehicle(routingContext, client);

        fetchVehicle.compose(vehicleJson -> vehicleDoor(routingContext, client, vehicleJson, lock)).setHandler(
                asyncResult -> {
                    if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    LOG.info("Door operation succeeded with result {}", asyncResult.result().encode());
                    handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new AsyncReply(200, "OK")));
                }
                else {
                    handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(asyncResult.cause()));
                }
        });
```

where we handle 2 calls for example.

OR I have another snippet where I can handle any number of methods:

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        conversation.getRequestList().forEach(req -> {
            Future<Message<Object>> senderFuture = Future.future();
            vertx.eventBus().send(AbstractOEMClientVerticle.ADDRESS, JsonObject.mapFrom(req), deliveryOptions, senderFuture.completer());

            // sent successfully. save the replyAddress and the conversation for later/callback
            log.info("Saving the conversation for the request.", conversation.getReplyAddress());
            pendingCommands.put(req.getBody().getString(MSG_ID), conversation);

            futures.add(senderFuture);
        });

        CompositeFuture.all(futures).setHandler(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture());
            } else {
                log.error("forwardToVWClient VW got result : {}", ar.cause());
                handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar.cause()));
            }
        });
```

Here we are chaining all the requests in the `conversation.getRequestList()` without knowing their count in advance.

But the shortcoming of `.all()` method is that, we have no control on the order.

**How can I chain any number of methods with Vertx Futures (without knowing the exact count of the calls) ?**

**EDIT:**

The official guide  talks about sequential composition but the example given has 3 calls. It does not explain how to do it for arbitrary number of calls.

See "Sequential composition" in http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/

I hope it is clear.

Comment: i think 3 being the number of `Future`s used in the example *is* arbitrary. there's no requirement that it need be 3. or have i misunderstood the question?

Comment: thanks for the feedback @homerman What i meant was that, I have to be able to handle when the total number of calls is not predefined. In the example of vertx official guide, 3 is arbitrary but predefined. right? does it make sense?

Comment: Take the 3 example and the code snippet, what if we donT know how many calls there will be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using `map & reduce` that executes a method in an orderly fashion and returns the accumulated result in the form of a `Future<String>`

```
 public static <T> Future<String> chainCall(List<T> list, Function<T, Future<String>> method){
        return list.stream().reduce(Future.succeededFuture(),// the initial "future"
                (acc, item) -> acc.compose(v -> method.apply(item)), // we return the compose of the previous "future" with "future" returned by next item processing
                (a,b) -> Future.future()); // not used! only useful for parallel stream.
    }
```

can be used as in the example below:

```
 chainCall(conversation.getRequestList(), this::sendApiRequestViaBus);
```

where `sendApiRequestViaBus` is:

```
/**
     * @param request The request to process
     * @return The result of the request processing. 
     */
    Future<String> sendApiRequestViaBus(ApiRequest request) {
        Future<String> future = Future.future();
        String address = CommandUtilsFactory.getInstance(request.getImplementation()).getApiClientAddress();
        log.debug("Chain call start msgId {}", request.getId());

        vertx.eventBus().send(address, JsonObject.mapFrom(request), deliveryOptions, res -> {
            log.debug("Chain call returns {}", request.getId());
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                future.complete("OK");
            } else {
                future.fail("KO");
            }
        });
        return future;
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to feed the response from the previous request to the next request, and suppose you have different handlers for each response. You can add a helper method

```
private <T> Future<T> chain(Future<T> init, List<Function<T, Future<T>>> handlers) {
    Future<T> result = init;
    for (Function<T, Future<T>> handler : handlers) {
        result = result.compose(handler);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And then change your code like this

```
    Future<JsonObject> fetchVehicle = getUserBookedVehicle(routingContext, client);

    Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>> vehicleResponseHandler = vehicleJson ->
        vehicleDoor(routingContext, client, vehicleJson, lock);

    Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>> anotherTrivialHandler = someJsonObj -> {
        // add here new request by using information from someJsonObj
        LOG.info("Hello from trivial handler {} ", someJsonObj);
        return Future.succeededFuture(someJsonObj);
    };

    List<Function<JsonObject, Future<JsonObject>>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

    handlers.add(vehicleResponseHandler);
    handlers.add(anotherTrivialHandler);

    chain(fetchVehicle, handlers).setHandler( asyncResult -> {
        if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new AsyncReply(200, "OK")));
        } else {
            handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(asyncResult.cause()));
        }
    });
```

But there is a limitation for this implementation which requires each chained `Future`   must have the same type parameter `T`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I add the result from each handler to a array that will be available when all of the futures succeed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something handy. Hope it helps.

```
public static <R> Future<List<R>> allOfFutures(List<Future<R>> futures) {
    return CompositeFutureImpl.all(futures.toArray(new Future[futures.size()]))
            .map(v -> futures.stream()
                    .map(Future::result)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single Future, loop over your futures and use `compose` to chain them:

```java
// single future variable
Future<Void> myFuture = Future.succeededFuture();

// iterate `myCount` times
for (int i = 0; i < myCount; i++) {
  // chain a call to myFuture from above
  myFuture.compose(v -> {
    // do something async
    return someMethodThatReturnsAFuture();
  }).compose(futureResult -> {
    // do something else async
    return someOtherMethodReturningAFuture(futureResult);
  });
}

// all futures are chained and executed after each other
// if one fails, consecutive futures are not executed and myFuture will fail
// if all succeed, myFuture will succeed too 
myFuture.onComplete(...);
```