# How Vert.x deal with cycle by cycle?

Tags: java, vert.x

This is shown in the following code:

```
public Future<Boolean> sendHeartbeat(List<BrokerMeta> brokerMetas) {

    PromiseInternal<Boolean> resultPromise = ContextInternal.current().promise();
    for (BrokerMeta brokerMeta : brokerMetas) {
        if (null == brokerMeta.getAdr()) {
            continue;
        }
        remote(brokerMeta.getAdr());
    }

    return resultPromise.future();
}

private Future<String> remote(String addr) {
    PromiseInternal<String> promise = ContextInternal.current().promise();
    // Request remote....
    promise.complete("From remote");
    return promise.future();
}
```

I want the Remote methods to execute one by one and return, and then I'm pushing resultPromise down,How do I write this code?

Comment: if you are looking for in depth vertx consulting - reach out using the link in my profile

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.compose` on the future sent from the `remote(string addr)` function to make sure they run one after the other i.e. the last future returned from the remote function will call compose on it and assign it to a new future which in the next iteration would call compose on it and so on

Ref: [Sequential composition for arbitrary number of calls in Vertx with Futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207723/sequential-composition-for-arbitrary-number-of-calls-in-vertx-with-futures)

Stuff like this is a lot easier when you use kotlin with coroutines - because then each call can just `suspend` before moving on to the next iteration - so would highly recommend looking into kotlin if you are using vert.x